# How to nest two Queries with Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I do have a table that has multiples visitors in it. In my result list only the last visit of each visitor should be shown.

the table looks like:

```
id | created_at | descr | website | source
------------------------------------------
2  | 2017_12_22 | john | john1.com | a
3  | 2017_12_23 | marc | ssdff.com | b
4  | 2017_12_24 | john | john1.com | c
5  | 2017_12_24 | tina | def.com   | b
6  | 2017_12_25 | stef | abc.com   | a
7  | 2017_12_26 | john | john2.com | c
```

If I do an

```
->orderBy('visitors.created_at', 'desc')
->groupBy('visitors.descr')
```

the result list is correct as only each visitor is shown once. But I need the latest occurrence of a visitor and the result list shows the first occurrence. So instead of ID 2 I would like to see ID 7.

The following query solves that issue:

```
select *
from visitors as v 
INNER JOIN ( select descr , MAX(created_at) as max_created
from visitors as v
group by descr ) AS M 
where v.descr = M.descr AND v.created_at = M.max_created
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Could someone help get this into eloquent or get me into another direction?

Comment: Can you post the Eloquent query that is not working (inverted)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the AUTO_INCREMENT `id` column instead of `created_at`, you can use another way to get the (same) result:

```
select *
from visitors
where id in (
    select MAX(id)
    from visitors
    group by descr
)
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This query is probably less efficient, but it's easier to use with eloquent, since `whereIn()` supports subqueries.

```
$subQuery = Visitor::groupBy('descr')->select(DB::raw('max(id)'));
$latestVisitors = Visitor::whereIn('id', $subQuery)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Note that your original query can return multiple rows per `descr`, if the value in `created_at` is the same. This can't happen using `id` since it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just query the sql directly like this:

```
DB::table('visitors')->select("
  select *
  from visitors as v 
  INNER JOIN ( select descr , MAX(created_at) as max_created
  from visitors as v
  group by descr ) AS M 
  where v.descr = M.descr AND v.created_at = M.max_created
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
");
```

In eloquent the query would be something like this:

```
DB::table('visitors as v')
->join(DB::raw("( select descr , MAX(created_at) as max_created
from visitors as v
group by descr ) AS M "),'v.id','=','M.id')
->select('*')
->where('v.descr','M.descr')->where('v.created_at','M.max_created')
->orderBy('created_at','desc')
->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper relationship in your Visitor model

```
public function lastVisit()
{
    $this->hasOne('VisitModel')->latest();
}
```

and then just fetch all visitors with their last visit

```
$visitors = Visitor::with('lastVisit')->get();
```

That's really all there is to it.